# Network interface provisioning state is failed when editing backend pool

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

I have a web server with PHP and apache.
I attached it to the app gateway and I still can't access my application.
When i enter my site URL: HTTP://<test.test.com> i get:

```
502 Bad Gateway
Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2
```

I have created a health prob and when I enter the IP address of the VM with the domain name to my host file I can access the system.

the strange thing is when I edit my backend pool I get this error and I can't find the answer anywhere

[image]

EDIT:

@KenWMSFT helped with solving the error in the screenshot, now when I enter the Application Gateway I get this warning:

```
All the instances in one or more of your backend pools are unhealthy. This will result in a 502 error when you try to access your application hosted behind the Application Gateway. Please check the backend health and resolve the issue.
```

Also I don't see any Backend health and I don't see a way to configure it...

Comment: If possible, try to reset the VM NIC in question.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/reset-network-interface

Comment: @KenWMSFT well the error is gone from the backend pool but I still get an error 502 when accessing via HTTP and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when accessing via HTTPS